# Increasing date by the hour

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Each time I click on the hour button or minute button it should populate a textbox and increase the hour by 1 each button click within a 24 hour format. The same applies for the minute button. Currently it is not iterating and is only increasing by one only once.

```
private void Cld_SelectedDateChanged(object sender,vhCalendar.SelectedDateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = e.NewDate.ToString();
    txtHH.Text = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString();
    txtMM.Text = DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();
}

private void btnAddHour_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    txtHH.Text = DateTime.Today.AddHours( 1 ).ToString("HH");
}

private void btnAddMinute_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    txtMM.Text = DateTime.Today.AddMinutes( 1 ).ToString( "mm" );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime.AddHours() and DateTime.AddMinutes() both return a new instance of DateTime when they are called. You should keep record of the returned instance and call it the next time you click the Hour button or the Minute button. This is how your code should look like:

```
private DateTime m_LastDateTime;

private void Cld_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    m_LastDateTime = e.Start;
    textBox1.Text = m_LastDateTime.ToString();
    txtHH.Text =m_LastDateTime.Hour.ToString();
    txtMM.Text =m_LastDateTime.Minute.ToString();
}

private void btnAddHour_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    m_LastDateTime = m_LastDateTime.AddHours(1);
    txtHH.Text = m_LastDateTime.ToString("HH");
}

private void btnAddMinute_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    m_LastDateTime = m_LastDateTime.AddMinutes(1);
    txtMM.Text = m_LastDateTime.ToString( "mm" );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are adding one to `current date` each time you click, if you look at the code, you need to be adding 1 to the current date value of the text box, but you are adding it to `DateTime.Today` over and over with each click.

So, `tryparse` the current value in the text box if not empty, otherwise set to current date and then add the minute / hour to this value.

for example, it would be something like this...

```
private void btnAddHour_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    DateTime curDate;
    DateTime.TryParse(txtHH.Text, out curDate);
    txtHH.Text =curDate.AddHours( 1 ).ToString("HH");
}
```

this is assuming the text box is populated, or you'll need to assign this first.

If the text box has no value, you can get the result of `TryParse`, and set the value to the current date.

```
private void btnAddHour_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    DateTime curDate;
    bool isParsed = DateTime.TryParse(txtHH.Text, out curDate);
    if (!isParsed)
      curDate = DateTime.Now;
    txtHH.Text =curDate.AddHours( 1 ).ToString("HH");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Today` returns is something like `21/08/2013 00:00:00`.
This will return the same `DateTime`every time you will call it.

You will need to either add a counter of clicks and add the counter or to store the initial result from `DateTime.Today` and keep increasing it.

Note that if the date changed in the middle of the application execution the second solution is the one you need to use since in the first solution the day will be increased without you wanting it to.